# How to make simulation run faster in netlogo instead of using Slider bar near to view update

Tags: netlogo

Is there any code to make simulation run faster in netlogo,  instead of using slider bar near to setting?  What my code need to do is to simulate the crowd behavior, it's work fine if the number of turtles around 100,however when I increase the number up to 300-800 turtles,  simulation take very long to finish.  Each tick also take very long to count from 0 to 1 and next until all turtles die. one thing that I suspect cause slow simulation is when ask turtles to evacuate. without evacuate rule, everything went smoothly even set a maximum number of turtles. is there other way to write evacuate rule, so that it can run faster? thanks.

```
to go
  ask turtles [wander fd 0.01]

  if emergency? = true [move]
  if all? turtles [ pcolor = red ]   ;stops simuation
  [stop]
  tick
end

to wander
  [ do..something]
end

to move
  set time-to-evacuate time-to-evacuate + 1
  ask turtles [avoid-obstacles fd 0.1]
  ask turtles [follow-leader fd 0.1]
  ask turtles [flock fd 0.1]
  ask turtles with [pcolor != red] [evacuate fd 0.1]
  ask turtles with [pcolor = red][die]
end

to evacuate
  ask turtles with [color = black ]
  [let beings-seen patches in-cone 10 135 with [pcolor = red] 
    if any? beings-seen 
    [ let target one-of beings-seen
      face target]]

  ask turtles with [color = white ]
  [let beings-seen patches in-cone 5 135 with [pcolor = red] 
    if any? beings-seen 
    [ let target one-of beings-seen
      face target]]
end

to avoid-obstacles
  [do something]
end

to follow-leader
  [do something]
end

to flock
  [do something]
end
```

Comment: `in-cone` is computationally very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

In your `move` procedure you have:

```
ask turtles with [pcolor != red] [ evacuate ... ]
```

And then in `evacuate` you have:

```
ask turtles with [color = black] [ ... ]
```

`evacuate` is already being run by all of the non-red turtles, so you've got every non-red turtle asking every black turtle to do something at every time tick.

I don't think you intended that.

I have to guess a bit at your intent, but I think if in `evacuate` you replace the `ask` with an `if`:

```
if color = black [ ... ]
```

that's probably closer to what you meant.